# Learning a new programming language

Tags: windows, gratis, software-development, programming

I want to learn a new programming language and that language should combine a few features I know from other programming languages and should avoid the things I dislike from those.

Must have:

- object orientation (like C# and Java)
- proper Unicode support (unlike PHP)
- generics (like C#, not like C++ templates)
- type safety (like C#, unlike C++)
- real multi-threading (like C# or C++, unlike Python)
- UI support, ideally in a native-looking way (like C# WinForms, unlike what you can do with C# WPF, I really dislike fancy UIs with colorful buttons, rounded edges, shadows and animations everywhere, sorry)

Must not have:

- undefined behavior (like C++)
- multi inheritance (like C++)
- HTML + CSS user interface
- duck typing (like Python, except duck typing is explicit)
- interpreter (like Python)

Should have:

- Namespaces (like C#) or packages (like Java)
- Lambda expressions
- Simple way of defining data classes (like C# `record`)
- Source code formatting/indentation required (like Python)

Should not have:

- `===` operators (like PHP or JavaScript)

Does not need:

- partial classes and methods (like C#)
- nested classes and local functions (like C#)

I'm uncertain/inconclusive about and would try either:

- garbage collection (like C#, Java) versus RAII (C++)
- compile to IL (like C#) or ByteCode (like Java) versus native code (C++)

Ideally it comes with a rich IDE like the JetBrains ones or Visual Studio, so that I can do most things in one place. The programming language should be gratis, the IDE needn't be.

Comment: Maybe SO will be better place for this question

Comment: @RomeoNinov: from the users who visit the site, I agree. But I'm pretty sure it would be closed as "opinion based" really soon. They don't like product or tool requests over there.

Comment: About question: what I see is `C#` is repeated as name a lot. But check also `python` . P.S. I am not programmer so my opinion is not so valuable :)

Comment: I'm using Python for 3+ years now. It's really ok for a lot of tasks.

Comment: Please note this site is about recommending software meeting specific requirements – not approaches, [languages](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/36/185), [technologies](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2451/185) or [algorithms](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/865/185).

Comment: @Izzy: I am not asking for a language to use in a project. I am asking for the language itself and I have specific requirements for that language. I don't think it's covered by that meta discussion, or rather: basically what the second answer says.

Comment: Well, that's IMHO much on the wrong side of the borderline – but I won't decide that alone then. You've posted your stance to the meta question already, so let's see if there will be votes on it and which.

Comment: @Izzy No need to reopen immediately. I can wait for some discussion and other opinions.

Comment: @ThomasWeller you're an "old hand" here and well trusted. Should the outcome be it's off-topic, you'll notice that long before I do. So easier for me to reopen now and leave it to you – than having to set myself a reminder and check every now and then, wouldn't you agree? :) Just please flag it for closure (unless you can close it yourself) should the result indeed be "OT". Othherwise, should the community decide it's OT before (by throwing 5 flags), that will be that then until decided otherwise #D Thanks!

Comment: PS: The curse of the moderator status: I can no longer throw "close votes" – they are binding immediately. Were my vote "one of five", I had probably left it as-is…